# Opening file geodatabases created with ogr2ogr in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, gdal, ogr, file-geodatabase

I've been using the new FileGDB support in gdal-1.9.0 to create file geodatabases that can be opened in ArcGIS.  For example (I'm doing this all on one line, so I'm not certain this will run as indented here):

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f 'FileGDB' \
    -sql "SELECT 
              CAST(gml_id AS character(255)), id, 
              CAST(scene_id AS character(255)), 
              CAST(license_type AS character(255)), 
              CAST(url AS character(255))
          FROM SDMI_Inventory" \
    sdmi_inv.gdb \
    WFS:"http://wfs.alaskamapped.org/inventory"
```

This worked great until 10.0 Service Pack 4, at which point ArcMap / ArcCatalog started reporting errors similar to this when you try to add / preview the layer:

```
Error opening feature class
The item does not have a definition. [SDMI_Inventory]
The item does not have a definition.
The XML being loaded could not be parsed. [physical name: SDMI_INVENTORY]
The item does not have a definition.
The XML being loaded could not be parsed. [physical name: SDMI_INVENTORY]
```

I've got the latest (1.2) API and the latest GDAL (1.9.0), x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Anyone have any ideas how to get this to work again?

Comment: perhaps try to upgrade the database first with catalog?

Comment: Brad, it is broken in SP4 whether you start a new geodatabase or overwrite an existing one.

Comment: you mean with ogr right?  I wonder create using esri, ogr in to another store, and ogr back out? Might help prove if it is gdal or not then you could hit the gdal dev group for an update. (basically doing some of the legwork for the devs)

Comment: I guess you would need to create an esri gdbapi specific and see if it is broken. then you could say it was gdal.

Comment: Yes, a FileGDB created with ogr alone is fine with ArcGIS 10.0 SP3, but broken in SP4.  I suspect it's an ArcGIS issue, not GDAL, but I don't know for sure.  I was hoping there was an ogr flag related to metadata that might fix it.

Answer (score 3):

[I did a search for geodatabase and found the following...](https://gisupdates.esri.com/10sp4/ArcGIS/ArcGIS10sp4-issues.htm)

> NIM065375 - Incorrect renaming of the Geodatabase object within ArcCatalog; results in corruption of GDB_items table and makes the renamed objects unusable within ArcCatalog.

Also [Several known issues in regard to versions](https://support.esri.com/en-us/search)
Surely you have already been here...
[gdal.org/ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html)
[issue Tracker](https://web.archive.org/web/20140814230949/http://upstream-tracker.org/versions/gdal.html)
[This shows some issues](https://web.archive.org/web/20140815022119/http://upstream-tracker.org/compat_reports/gdal/1.8.1_to_1.9.0/abi_compat_report.html#Added) in regard to spatial reference. perhaps updating the srs prior to opening might help.
Just grasping at some straws here maybe one will cause some resolve.
You are kind of in between the [gdal\dev](https://lists.osgeo.org/) and the [gdb API\dev](https://forums.arcgis.com/forums/126-File-Geodatabase-API)